# How to add add a TreeModelListener to the NetBeans Outline?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm using the NetBeans Outline model to create a TreeTable, the technique is described  [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component):

Everything looks nice and clean and I now want add a TreeModelListener to my model to listen for changes in the model:

```
Outline outline = new Outline();
MyNode root = new MyNode("data", 0);
//...
TreeModel treeMdl = new MyTreeModel(root);
OutlineModel mdl = 
DefaultOutlineModel.createOutlineModel(treeMdl, new MyRowModel(), true, "Data");
mdl.addTreeModelListener(new MyTreeModelListener());
outline.setModel(mdl);
//...

public class MyTreeModelListener implements TreeModelListener {
    public void treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Something happend");

    }

    public void treeNodesInserted(TreeModelEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void treeNodesRemoved(TreeModelEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void treeStructureChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Everything works as expected, but my problem is below, I have written my own TreeModel class and that obviously means that I have to write my own `addTreeModelListener` method, but how do I do that?

```
public class MyTreeModel implements TreeModel {

    private MyNode root;

    public MyTreeModel(SdbNode root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    @Override
    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        //TODO:
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Can you please post how you implemented the removal of nodes from the NetBeans Outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList` will handle most of the heavy lifting. The class parameter to the `add`, `remove`, and `getListeners` methods allow you to store all of your listeners in one list, then extract a subset of only the type you want.

Note: the class parameter is the class of the *interface*, not the class of the *implementation*.

It basically looks like this:

```
    private EventListenerList listeners = null;

    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        if (l == null)
            return;
        if (listeners == null)
            listeners = new EventListenerList();
        listeners.add(TreeModelListener.class, l);
    }

    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        if (l == null)
            return;
        if (listeners == null)
            return;
        listeners.remove(TreeModelListener.class, l);
    }

    private void fireTreeStructureChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
        if (e == null)
            return;
        if (listeners == null)
            return;
        TreeModelListener[] ll = listeners.getListeners(TreeModelListener.class);
        for(int i = 0; i < ll.length; i++)
            ll.treeStructureChanged(e);
    }
```

If you're supporting the rest of the model notifications you'll need to implement variations on the last method that call `treeNodesInserted`, `treeNodesRemoved`, or `treeNodesChanged`